# Making a Canvas game responsive on resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to make a pong canvas game responsive on resize, i am nor sure what i am missing and what would be the best way to have it responsive while still not being to process heavy. i tried to delete and reinject the canvas on resize what is a bad idea i think, the responsiveness works on load so far... thanks a lot for the insights, much appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/ut0hsvd4/1/

```
var animate = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
  window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)
};
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var width = document.getElementById('pong').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('pong').offsetHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var player = new Player();
var computer = new Computer();
var ball = new Ball(width / 2, height / 2);

var keysDown = {};

var render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  player.render();
  computer.render();
  ball.render();
};

var update = function() {
  player.update();
  computer.update(ball);
  ball.update(player.paddle, computer.paddle);
};

var step = function() {
  update();
  render();
  animate(step);
};

function Paddle(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x_speed = 0;
  this.y_speed = 0;
}

Paddle.prototype.render = function() {
  context.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
  context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
};

Paddle.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  this.x_speed = x;
  this.y_speed = y;
  if (this.x < 0) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.x_speed = 0;
  } else if (this.x + this.width > width) {
    this.x = width - this.width;
    this.x_speed = 0;
  }
};

function Computer() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle(width / 2 - 25, 10, 50, 10);
}

Computer.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};

Computer.prototype.update = function(ball) {
  var x_pos = ball.x;
  var diff = -((this.paddle.x + (this.paddle.width / 2)) - x_pos);
  if (diff < 0 && diff < -4) {
    diff = -5;
  } else if (diff > 0 && diff > 4) {
    diff = 5;
  }
  this.paddle.move(diff, 0);
  if (this.paddle.x < 0) {
    this.paddle.x = 0;
  } else if (this.paddle.x + this.paddle.width > width) {
    this.paddle.x = width - this.paddle.width;
  }
};

function Player() {
  this.paddle = new Paddle(width / 2 - 25, height - 20, 50, 10);
}

Player.prototype.render = function() {
  this.paddle.render();
};

Player.prototype.update = function() {
  for (var key in keysDown) {
    var value = Number(key);
    if (value == 37) {
      this.paddle.move(-4, 0);
    } else if (value == 39) {
      this.paddle.move(4, 0);
    } else {
      this.paddle.move(0, 0);
    }
  }
};

function Ball(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.x_speed = 0;
  this.y_speed = 3;
}

Ball.prototype.render = function() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = "#000000";
  context.fill();
};

Ball.prototype.update = function(paddle1, paddle2) {
  this.x += this.x_speed;
  this.y += this.y_speed;
  var top_x = this.x - 5;
  var top_y = this.y - 5;
  var bottom_x = this.x + 5;
  var bottom_y = this.y + 5;

  if (this.x - 5 < 0) {
    this.x = 5;
    this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
  } else if (this.x + 5 > width) {
    this.x = width - 5;
    this.x_speed = -this.x_speed;
  }

  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.x_speed = 0;
    this.y_speed = 3;
    this.x = width / 2;
    this.y = height / 2;
  }

  if (top_y > height / 2) {
    if (top_y < (paddle1.y + paddle1.height) && bottom_y > paddle1.y && top_x < (paddle1.x + paddle1.width) && bottom_x > paddle1.x) {
      this.y_speed = -3;
      this.x_speed += (paddle1.x_speed / 2);
      this.y += this.y_speed;
    }
  } else {
    if (top_y < (paddle2.y + paddle2.height) && bottom_y > paddle2.y && top_x < (paddle2.x + paddle2.width) && bottom_x > paddle2.x) {
      this.y_speed = 3;
      this.x_speed += (paddle2.x_speed / 2);
      this.y += this.y_speed;
    }
  }
};

document.getElementsByClassName('js-pong')[0].appendChild(canvas);
animate(step);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
});

var resizer = function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').remove();
  document.getElementsByClassName('js-pong')[0].appendChild(canvas);
  animate(step);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizer);
```

Comment: you can resize the canvas just by changing canvas.width, canvas.height, or am I missing something?

Comment: but that wont update the paddle position and size, i thought i would be a nother way instead of deleting and reinitialize the whole game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dont use the Resize event for animations.

*(if you use `requestAnimationFrame`)*

Do not add a resize to the resize event. The resize event does not fire in sync with the display, and it can also fire many time quicker than the display rate. This can make the resize and game feel sluggish while dragging at the window size controls.

#### Smooth and efficient resizing

For the smoothest resize simply check the canvas size inside the main loop. If the canvas does not match the containing element size then resize it. This ensures you only resize when needed and always resize in sync with the display (if you use `requestAnimationFrame`)

Eg

```
// get a reference to the element so you don't query the DOM each time
const pongEl = document.getElementById("pong");

// then in the main loop
function mainLoop() {
    // do first thing inside the render loop
    if(canvas.width !== pongEl.offsetWidth  || canvas.height !== pongEl.offsetHeight ){
        canvas.width = pongEl.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = pongEl.offsetHeight;   
        // note the above clears the canvas.
    }

    // game code as normal

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, i will try to implement it and report back :-)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the actual `canvas.height = whatever` calls are what take a really long time, regardless how they are scheduled.

Comment: @trusktr Please note that at the time of this answer browsers could fire more than one mouse event per frame meaning that listening to on-resize to change canvas resolution could result in needlessly resizing the canvas. If you wish to change the canvas size (scale) you can do so via CSS. The only way to change the canvas size (resolution) is via the canvas width and height properties

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks. Yeah, looks like I found a browser bug with the compositor (layering transparent canvas on CSS content, then changing canvas size is extremely slow).

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect when the resize happens with JavaScript:

`window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};`

and add a css class or properties to make the canvas width 100%. Also you have to give it a  min-width to make sure no body can resize it to a really uncomfortable width.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code needs to run again after a resize:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var width = document.getElementById('pong').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('pong').offsetHeight;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```